# Using Python 3.6 Threading with a list of locks

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, locks

I have an executable which I have been using with a variety of starting conditions. It may run hundreds of times depending on the range of inputs I provide. Speeding this up is a high priority and so I've tried to use Thread and a list of locks.

The reason for a list of locks is to limit the total load on my 6 core CPU. So I've chosen 3 locks for this post but I plan on using 5.

I'm showing three different attempts, each failing a different way.

1. The range of inputs never advances, i.e. only the first combination gets used before the program exits. (loop over lock_list and if lock.locked(): break)
2. Each input is ran n_locks times. (loop over lock_list)
3. Doesn't actually run concurrently. (break after each lock in lock_list)

I'm not showing the actual program calls just the ways that I have tried to implement Thread.

```
import threading
import time
import random

# Random seed for reproducibility
random.seed(123)

# Limit the number of active threads using locks
n_locks = 3
lock_list = list()

# Create a list that holds the desired number of locks
for i in range(n_locks):
    lock_list.append(threading.Lock())

# Some dummy data for use in the function to be threaded
aa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
bb = [3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4]

# The function to be used, where execution time may vary
def multiply(a, b):
    print(a, b, a * b)
    time.sleep(random.random() * 0.5)


# Show the inputs and outputs without threading
print('Unthreaded output...')

for d1, d2 in zip(aa, bb):
    multiply(d1, d2)

# The same function, but using 'with lock:'
def multiply_threaded(l, a, b):
    with l:
        print(a, b, a * b)
        time.sleep(random.random() * 1.0)


# Here's where I'm having a problem...
print('\nThreaded Ouptut, 1st Try')
for d1, d2 in zip(aa, bb):
    for lk in lock_list:
        if lk.locked():
            break
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=multiply_threaded, args=(lk, d1, d2)).start()

time.sleep(1.5)
print('The data set is never advanced...')
# Sleep to wait for the 2nd attempt...

# 2nd Try
print('\nThreaded Ouptut, 2nd Try')
for d1, d2 in zip(aa, bb):
    for lk in lock_list:
        threading.Thread(target=multiply_threaded, args=(lk, d1, d2)).start()

time.sleep(5.5)
print('The data set is used 3 times...')


# 3rd Try
print('\nThreaded Ouptut, 3rd Try')
for d1, d2 in zip(aa, bb):
    for lk in lock_list:
        threading.Thread(target=multiply_threaded, args=(lk, d1, d2)).start()
        break

time.sleep(5.5)
print("Doesn't appear to be executed concurrently...")
```

Below is the output:

```
Unthreaded output...
1 3 3
2 4 8
3 3 9
4 4 16
5 3 15
6 4 24
7 3 21
8 4 32

Threaded Ouptut, 1st Try
1 3 3
1 3 3
1 3 3
The data set is never advanced...

Threaded Ouptut, 2nd Try
1 3 3
1 3 3
1 3 3
2 4 8
2 4 8
2 4 8
3 3 9
4 4 16
3 3 9
5 3 15
4 4 16
3 3 9
5 3 15
4 4 16
5 3 15
6 4 24
6 4 24
6 4 24
7 3 21
7 3 21
8 4 32
8 4 32
7 3 21
8 4 32
The data set is used 3 times...

Threaded Ouptut, 3rd Try
1 3 3
2 4 8
3 3 9
4 4 16
5 3 15
6 4 24
7 3 21
8 4 32
Doesn't appear to be executed concurrently...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I am expecting to see is similar to the unthreaded output and try #3, except that the order shouldn't necessarily be in the order the inputs were given as the sleep function was used to simulate the load of the executable.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

EDIT: I use os.system("C:\my_exe.exe > C:\my_output.txt) in the actual Thread. I can't access the exe or supporting files when they are in use so I've made copies so the Threads can each use one.d

Comment: This sounds like you really need either a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects), a thread pool (see `multiprocessing.dummy` or `concurrent.futures`), or a process-based solution. A list of locks doesn't sound like the way to go.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you for the input. I'll check on those. A threadpool sounds promising.